# building redash chart over prometheus

Tags: prometheus, redash

I'm trying to create Redash chart based on query from prometheus data source:
 `rate(active_devices_count[1w])`. I'm expecting to see a date/value based graph, just as I see in our Grafana, but instead I see only single line on the graph. I looks like redash showing only last retrived value.
[image: redash first query]
[image: grafana first query]

on query like `active_devices_count` I see dot only, while in grafana I can see graph as well
[image: redash second query]
[image: grafana second query]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just append a time range to your query in Redash like:

```
rate(active_devices_count[1w])&start=2021-09-20T00:00:00.000Z&end=2021-09-21T00:00:00.000Z&step=3600s
```

The query will automatically be converted to a range query and your graph will work as expected.